# Is there a CSS solution for non-expanding space?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with `style="text-align:justify"` and inside it is a list of hyperlinks. In Firefox, only the white space ~between~ hyperlinks expands, which looks good. But in Chrome, the white space ~within~ the links also expands, which looks strange.

I tried changing those spaces to `&nbsp;`, but they expand too.

Currently my solution is to make all link spaces into spans containing a transparent character, but that's a bit goofy:

```
<a href="test.html">one<span style="color:transparent;">x</span>link</a>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: please post a minimal reproduciable code snippet showing the issue (ctrl + m). Also you have paddings and margins to create white space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine HTML node tree:

```
div
  a
    some other stuff
```

Your div can have `text-align: justify;` but try to apply `text-align: left;` for `a` element then.

Or, your div can be flex container (`display: flex;`) with style `justify-content: space-between;`, so your hyperlinks will have even space between each other.

Comment: Applying text-align:left to the links didn't work for me, but using display:flex along with justify-content:space-between and flex-wrap:wrap did work. Thank you!